# Refining this regex to capture enclosed string between asterisks like **(str)**

Tags: javascript, regex

[Regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/dO8J3d/8)

I'm trying to bold a string placed between ** as in `**hello**` to `<b>hello</b>`. It seemed easy at first, but due to cases like `***a**` and `**a***`, I had to add some long patterns. The current regex is this :

```
\*\*((?:\*(?!\*)[^*]*)*([^*])*(?:[^*]*(?<!\*)\*)*)\*\*
```

#### Breaking down the regex

**part1
`(?:\*(?!\*)[^*]*)*`** captures something like `*abc` that doesn't have additional * before it meaning, it won't capture `**abc`. Added to process `**ab***` as `<b>ab*</b>`

**part2
`([^*])*`** captures normal characters that are not `*`

**part3
`(?:[^*]*(?<!\*)\*)*`** captures something like `abc*` that doesn't have additional * after it. meaning, it won't capture `abc**`. Added to process `***ab**` as `<b>*ab</b>`

#### Expected Result Table

```
**a** → <b>a</b>           : success
***a** → <b>*a</b>         : success
**a*** → <b>a*</b>         : success
**a*a** → <b>a*a</b>       : fail with the current regex
**a**a** → <b>a</b>a**     : success
```

#### Code with replacement function

```
const reBoldLine = /\*\*((?:\*(?!\*)[^*]*)*([^*])*(?:[^*]*(?<!\*)\*)*)\*\*/g;
const strs = [
  '**a**',
  '***a**',     
  '**a***',     
  '***a***',
  '**a*a**'
]

const replacer = function(match, ...args){
  if(match){
    return "<b>"+args[0]+"</b>"
  }else{
    return "undefined"
  }
}

for(let str of strs){
  console.log(str.replace(reBoldLine, replacer))
}
```

edit : Replaced long explanation with expected result

Comment: So `**a***` should become `<b>a*</b>` or `<b>a</b>*`?

Comment: if you could put your cases and expected results in a table, that would really help with the comprehension of your question

Comment: I believe just a simple `/\*\*(.*?)\*\*/` will work for most of usecases.

Comment: Your logic for `**ab***` conflicts with how `**a**b**` gets handled. @anubhava has a good solution overall.

Comment: I would add (\w|\s)+ to @anubhava 's solution to cover a string containing a new line:
`/\*\*((\w|\s)+|(.+))\*\*/`

Comment: Thanks for examples but rules of transformation are not clear. Case #3 and Case #5  appear to be contradictory.

Comment: @anubhava You are right... The case 3 violates the basic rule ("close when it meets two asteriks") and trying to give it an exception is causing all sorts of havocs. I gotta settle on a simpler but more consistent approach. Thank you!